i want to create a modal, when i click on button having id a modal should be opened having card
i have created a courses page and create a fullscreen which should be opened when button is clicked modal is also opened but i am having an error in JS.
let value = colc[details.target.id]
if(details.target.tagName == "BUTTON"){

       

        fullscreen.style.opacity = 1;
        fullscreen.style.pointerEvents = "auto";

       inData = `<div id="fsCard">
                <h1>${value.heading}</h1>
                </div>
            `
     
}
   i am having error in value.heading 

i tried to create a modal which should be opened when button is clicked and it is opening but modal dont contain a card which i have created in event listener

It is not clear where the value variable has been declared and it is not clear which value there set as well as the error you get. Please add more details and code samples.

for HTML modal use <dialog> element.

When you create a dialog, you can add your card via innerHTML.


document.getElementById('button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    const dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
    
    dialog.innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
    dialog.open = true;
  });
  
document.getElementById('dialog')
  .addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
    target.open = false;
  });
<input id="input" value="This will show up in the modal">
<button id="button">Click me</button>

<dialog id="dialog"></dialog>



